# Pass multipart/form-data through API Gateway in Lambda Proxy integration

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload multiple files through the API Gateway in a lambda proxy integration using multipart/form-data. I added the multipart/form-data as one of the supported media types in the API Gateway settings. The issue that I am having is that the API Gateway is encoding it in Base64 when it passes it to the lambda proxy. Is there a way to disable this encoding and forward the data as it is to the lambda proxy?

Comment: Have you redeployed your API after you saved your changes? Adding 'multipart/form-data' without redeploying your API has no effect.

Comment: Yes, I did that but it didn't help

Comment: and you're also adding the content-type header on your request?

Comment: yes, I am doing all of that.